# Nethereum get Last Block Number

Tags: nethereum

I would like to get something similar to solidity

```
block.number - 1
```

using Nethereum

```
BlockParameter.CreateLatest()
```

Is latest here mean the Last BlockNumber been mined? Or do I need to minus 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var latestBlockNumber = await web3.Eth.Blocks.GetBlockNumber.SendRequestAsync();
```

See the bottom example located here: https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nethereum.Workbooks/docs/nethereum-gettingstarted-infura/

Which I posted above ^.